# Django form fields are not displayed

Tags: python, django

I want to make a form for adding comments, but I only display a form without fields for input, it does not give any errors.
[how it looks on the web-site](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/545279509218459660/792498265924435968/unknown.png), there should be a form to post a comment.

I would also like to know how this code can be improved.

Any help is appreciated!

Here is my **forms.py**:

```
    class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Comment
            fields = ['body']
```

**views.py:**

```
def comments(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cf = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        if cf.is_valid():
            body = request.POST.get('body')
            comment = Comment.objects.create(post=post, user=request.name, body=body)
            comment.save()
            return redirect(post.get_absolute_url())
        else:
            cf = CommentForm()

        context = {
            'cf': cf,
        }
        return render(request, 'main/article_detail.html', context)
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListViews.as_view(), name='articles'),
    path('article/<int:pk>/', PostDetailViews.as_view(), name='articles-detail'),
    path('register/', register, name='register'),
    path('login/', login, name='login'),
]
```

**My form in template:**

```
             <form method="POST">
             {% csrf_token %}
             {{ cf.as_p }}
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100px;position: relative;">Submit</button>
             </form>
```

my **models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Comment {self.body} by {self.name}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **views.py**

```
def comments(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cf = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        if cf.is_valid():
            comment = cf.save(commit=False)
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.post = post # you also will have to query your post first (i presume thats what the id is for in the function declaration)
            comment.save()
            return redirect(post.get_absolute_url())
    else: # fix this
        cf = CommentForm()

        context = {
            'cf': cf,
        }
    return render(request, 'main/article_detail.html', context) # fix this
```

Your indentation is implying that the template will render only with the `POST` method, since when you're accessing the view you are calling a `GET` method, your `render` function never gets called.

Also just use regular `form.save()` method to save your objects to database, its much easier to understand. And you do have to query your `post` before assigning a comment to it.

Comment: I have no errors, but the input form is not displayed on the page, there is only a submit button, and if you click on it, then an error 405 appears.

Comment: try what Rahul said with just using `request.POST` when initializing the form instead of `request.POST or none`

Answer (score 0):

In your views, your else block is not indented with request.method if block and also use return render method...
Also use data=request.post in your parentheses bracket instead of "request.post or none". Try this....it should work then....